# How to compare two dates in php

Tags: php

How to compare two dates in php if dates are in format `'03_01_12'` and `'31_12_11'` .

I am using this code:

```
$date1=date('d_m_y');
$date2='31_12_11';
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2))
   echo '1 is small ='.strtotime($date1).','.$date1;
else
   echo '2 is small ='.strtotime($date2).','.$date2;
```

But its not working..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will have to make sure that your dates are valid date objects.

Try this:

```
$date1=date('d/m/y');
$tempArr=explode('_', '31_12_11');
$date2 = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $tempArr[1], $tempArr[0], $tempArr[2]));
```

You can then perform the `strtotime()` method to get the difference.

Comment: Why not str_replace?

Answer (score 46):

Using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$format = "d_m_y";
$date1  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "03_01_12");
$date2  = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "31_12_11");

var_dump($date1 > $date2);
```

Comment: When using d#m#Y, any of the supported seperators `;, :, (, ), /, ., ,, -` will work.

Answer (score 31):

*Not answering the OPs actual problem, but answering just the title. Since this is the top result for "comparing dates in php".*

Pretty simple to use Datetime Objects (`php >= 5.3.0`) and [Compare them directly](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2749)

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2009-10-11");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow"); // Can use date/string just like strtotime.
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
```

Comment: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @HikaruShindo: If you want to echo the DateTime object, you have to use the `format` method: `echo $date1->format('d/m/Y')` :)

Answer (score 14):

The date_diff() function returns the difference between two DateTime objects.

If the first date is before the second date a positive number of days will be returned; otherwise a negative number of days:

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

output will be  "+272 days" ;

changing 
$date1 = "2014-03-15"

```
 <?php
    $date1=date_create("2014-03-15");
    $date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
    echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
    ?>
```

Output will be  "-93 days"

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
       $expiry_date = "2017-12-31 00:00:00"
       $today = date('d-m-Y',time()); 
       $exp = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($expiry_date));
       $expDate =  date_create($exp);
       $todayDate = date_create($today);
       $diff =  date_diff($todayDate, $expDate);
       if($diff->format("%R%a")>0){
             echo "active";
       }else{
           echo "inactive";
       }
       echo "Remaining Days ".$diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ?

Answer (score 8):

Extending @nevermind's answer, one can use [DateTime::createFromFormat:](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) like,

```
// use - instead of _. replace _ by - if needed.
$format = "d-m-y";
$date1  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, date('d-m-y'));
$date2  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, str_replace("_", "-",$date2));    
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try something like:

```
$date1 = date_create('2014-1-23'); // format of yyyy-mm-dd
$date2 = date_create('2014-2-3'); // format of yyyy-mm-dd
$dateDiff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
var_dump($dateDiff);
```

You can then access the difference in days like this $dateDiff->d;

Comment: hey! thanks, there was a little typo in it the ']' character right? its close to the Enter Key, I must have pressed it along too.  Thanks for the look out.

Answer (score 3):

You can to converte for integer number and compare.

Eg.:

```
$date_1 = date('Ymd');
$date_2 = '31_12_2011';

$date_2 = (int) implode(array_reverse(explode("_", $date_2)));

echo ($date_1 < $date_2) ? '$date_2 is bigger then $date_1' : '$date_2 is smaller than $date_1';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$data1 = strtotime(\date("d/m/Y"));
$data1 = date_create($data1);
$data2 = date_create("21/06/2017");

if($data1 < $data2){
    return "The most current date is date1";
}

return "The most current date is date2";
```

Answer (score 3):

benchmark comparison
date_create, strtotime, DateTime, and direct

direct is faster

```
$f1="2014-12-12";
$f2="2014-12-13";
$diff=false;


$this->bench('a');
for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $date1=date_create($f1);
    $date2=date_create($f2);
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
}
$this->bench('a','b');
for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
     $date1=strtotime($f1);
     $date2=strtotime($f2);
     if ($date1>$date2) {
        $diff=true;
    }
}
$this->bench('b','c');
for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $date1 = new DateTime($f1);
    $date2 = new DateTime($f2);
    if ($date1>$date2) {
        $diff=true;
     }
}
$diff=false;
$this->bench('c','d');
for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
     if ($f1>$f2) {
        $diff=true;
     }
}
$this->bench('d','e');
var_dump($diff);

$this->dumpr($this->benchs);

results:

    [a] => 1610415241.4687
    [b] => 1610415242.8759
    [a-b] => 1.407194852829
    [c] => 1610415243.5672
    [b-c] => 0.69137716293335
    [d] => 1610415244.7036
    [c-d] => 1.1363649368286
    [e] => 1610415244.7109
    [d-e] => 0.0073208808898926
```

Answer (score 2):

compare the result of `maketime()` for each of the time

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what your problem is but:

```
function date_compare($d1, $d2)
{
    $d1 = explode('_', $d1);
    $d2 = explode('_', $d2);
    
    $d1 = array_reverse($d1);
    $d2 = array_reverse($d2);
    
    if (strtotime(implode('-', $d1)) > strtotime(implode('-', $d2)))
    {
        return $d2;
    }
    else
    {
        return $d1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but for future reference, put the date format into a recognised format by using str_replace then your function will work. (replace the underscore with a dash)

```
//change the format to dashes instead of underscores, then get the timestamp
$date1 = strtotime(str_replace("_", "-",$date1));
$date2 = strtotime(str_replace("_", "-",$date2));

//compare the dates
if($date1 < $date2){
   //convert the date back to underscore format if needed when printing it out.
   echo '1 is small='.$date1.','.date('d_m_y',$date1);
}else{
   echo '2 is small='.$date2.','.date('d_m_y',$date2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is very simple function

```
function terminateOrNotStringtoDate($currentDate, $terminationdate)
{
    $crtDate = new DateTime($currentDate);
    $termDate = new DateTime($terminationdate);
    if($crtDate >= $termDate)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys Please don't make it so complex The simple answer bellow

```
$date1=date('d_m_y');
$date2='31_12_11';
$date1=str_replace('_', '-', $date1);
$date2=str_replace('_', '-', $date2)
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2))
   echo '1 is small ='.strtotime($date1).','.$date1;
else
   echo '2 is small ='.strtotime($date2).','.$date2;
```

I just have added two more lines with your code

Answer (score -1):

If both dates are in the same format then use a comparison operator.

```
$date1 = "2018-05-05"; 
$date2 = "2019-08-19"; 

//comparison operator to  

if ($date1 > $date2) {
    echo "$date1 is latest than $date2"; 
    }
else{
    echo "$date1 is older than $date2"; 
    }
```

Output:
2018-05-05 is older than 2019-08-19

Comment: This will only work if the dates are in ISO 8601 format.