# Can not compare two date using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an issue while comparing two date inside if condition. I am providing my code below.

```
$erresult = mysqli_fetch_array($qrylast);
$ticket = $erresult['ticket_id'];
if ((date("Y-m-d") == $erresult['date'])) {
    $id = sprintf("%03d", $ticket++);
    $fields = array("date", "ticket_id ");
    $tablename = "db_ticket";
    $values = array(date("Y-m-d"), $id);
    $id1 = db_insert($tablename, $values, $fields);
    if ($id1) {
        $ticket_id = 'W1' . date("Ymd") . $id;
    }
} else {
    $id = '001';
    $fields = array("date", "ticket_id ");
    $tablename = "db_ticket";
    $values = array(date("Y-m-d"), $id);
    $id1 = db_insert($tablename, $values, $fields);
    if ($id1) {
        $ticket_id = 'W1' . date("Ymd") . $id;
    }
}
```

Here I need to compare today's date with date save inside database. My saved date inside database datatype is also date but here always else part is executing. In my code I have one condition `(date("Y-m-d")==$erresult['date'])` and this condition is never executing even two date are same.

Comment: If you're sure that `date("Y-m-d")` and `$erresult['date'])` are the same, you've to check your script call: are you sure that your posted code will be executed?

Comment: What you will get when print the $erresult['date']?

Comment: i am getting `2016-01-22` while print $erresult['date'] and its datatype is date in db.

Comment: Then your code is working fine and also your code is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) == strtotime($erresult['date']))
```

follow :- [How to compare two dates in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: I have also datatype as date in DB.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I used your answer but still issue is same.

Comment: its result is one while i checked doing echo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strtotime()` function to compare the two dates
e.g

```
if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) == strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$erresult['date'])))
```