# Compare a set of integers saved in different variables in php

Tags: php, integer, compare

I have 2 variables as below both having the same length of integers:

```
$var1 = 2016-08-03

$var2 = 2016-21-23
```

Basically, I need to compare both of them as below:

```
Step1: compare 2 from $var1 to 2 from $var2
both are same. proceed
Step2: compare 0 from $var1 to 0 from $var2
both are same. proceed
Step3: compare 1 from $var1 to 1 from $var2
both are same. proceed
Step4: compare 6 from $var1 to 6 from $var2
both are same. proceed
Step5: compare - from $var1 to - from $var2
both are same. proceed
Step6: compare 0 from $var1 to 2 from $var2
Result: $var2 is greater
```

Comment: those aren't integers by the way, those are strings

Comment: and do you really intend to compare them that way? or are you trying to check which date is greater?

Comment: I plan to use it for both date compare as well as the comparison mentioned above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php

Comment: I do not want to use any functions related to date for this. Also it is not always that these will be in this date format.