# PHP show date2 if date1 passed

Tags: php

I need help on this..
I am new in php and dummy..

```
$displaydate = "";

$paydate1 = "23-10-2016";
$paydate2 = "23-11-2016";   
$paydate3 = "23-12-2016";    
$paydate4 = "23-01-2017";    
$paydate5 = "23-02-2017";   
$paydate6 = "23-03-2017";




if todaydate is 23-10-2016 then $displaydate = "$paydate2" until 22-11-2016. When 23-11-2016 then $displaydate = "$paydate3" and so on.



then results    
if the date is 23-10-2016 until 22-11-2016 $displaydate = "$paydate2"   
if the date is 23-11-2016 until 22-12-2016 $displaydate = "$paydate3"    
if the date is 23-12-2016 until 22-01-2016 $displaydate = "$paydate4"   
if the date is 23-01-2016 until 22-02-2016 $displaydate = "$paydate5"  
if the date is 23-02-2016 until 22-03-2016 $displaydate = "$paydate6"
```

please help with the code...
Thanks..

IM php DUMMY

Comment: This is a lot of code to ask someone to make for you with little input from you. I will say that in order to do this, i would cast the date from a string to a date (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). PHP also allows you to compare two dates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php), so you would ensure that your date fits within the date range using a switch or series of if statements. This is something that you should do a little research and maybe learn some basic programming syntax before attempting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your data convenient so you can easy access it.
Put your paydates it an array:

```
$paydate = ["23-10-2016","23-11-2016","23-12-2016","23-01-2017","23-02-2017","23-03-2017"];
```

UPDATED per your comment:

```
$payout1 = $this->data->paymentdate1; 
$payout2 = $this->data->paymentdate2; 
$payout3 = $this->data->paymentdate3; 
$payout4 = $this->data->paymentdate4; 
$payout5 = $this->data->paymentdate5; 
$payout6 = $this->data->paymentdate6; 

$paydate = [$payout1,$payout2,$payout3,$payout4,$payout5,$pa‌​yout6];
```

Transform the dates in an easy to sort format:

```
function trf_date($date)
{
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
}
$paydate = array_map("trf_date", $paydate );
```

Sort the array to be sure we will get the dates in ascending order while looping.

```
sort($paydate);
```

Now loop through the array to find the first date higher then today:

```
foreach($paydate as $key=>$val){
   if($val > date('Y-m-d'))
     break;
}

$displaydate = ''; //initialize the output variable

//check to see if the last retrieved date meets the condition not to be in the past. 
//this is for the case all dates in the array are in the past
if(isset($paydate[$key]) && $paydate[$key] > date('Y-m-d'))
   $displaydate = $paydate[$key];
```

Comment: i got error on this Notice: Undefined variable: displaydate

Comment: $payout1 = $this->data->paymentdate1;
$payout2 = $this->data->paymentdate2;
$payout3 = $this->data->paymentdate3;
$payout4 = $this->data->paymentdate4;
$payout5 = $this->data->paymentdate5;
$payout6 = $this->data->paymentdate6;

$paydate = ["$payout1","$payout2","$payout3","$payout4","$payout5","$payout6"];


function trf_date($date)
{
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
}
$paydate = array_map("trf_date", $paydate );


sort($paydate);

foreach($paydate as $key=>$val){
   if($val > date('Y-m-d'))
     break;
}
if ($key > 0)
  $displaydate = $paydate[$key];

Comment: Don't use the quotes in the $paydate array. Build it like this:  `$paydate = [$payout1,$payout2,$payout3,$payout4,$payout5,$pa‌​yout6];`

Comment: I just a dummy of php.. could u help me to complete this? Thanks u so much~~

Comment: `if ($key > 0) ` is there to make sure you will not get _Undefined index_ error. Initialize your variable at the beginning of the script: `$displaydate = '';`

Comment: so it is safe and can it follow date by date? i scare the date will become like go random.. currently i remove `if ($key > 0)` no more the Undefined variable error..

Comment: I have updated the answer to also work for all dates in the array being in the past.