# Compare between Two dates in php

Tags: php

I have two dates i want to compare between two of them are they at the same time (year/month/day/hour)
i get time from database and the other time from user input i have used

```
$checkdate = strtotime($meetingDate);
$dateconflicts = strtotime($_SESSION['date']);

if ($checkdate == $dateconflicts ) {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>there's conflicts !</div>";                
}
```

the thing is it doesn't work like this i don't know why.

Comment: `strtotime()` returns a timestamp, which means that you are comparing two timestamps. So unless the datetime you've given is the exact same second, it will fail. You probably want to format it with dates instead, I recommend the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class.

Comment: it is answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php

Comment: value of `$_SESSION['date']` is what here? and was the session started? Edit: value of `$meetingDate` is what also?

Comment: $_SESSION['date'] from previous page the user enter date to create a new meeting in this time
$meetingDate is date from database every user has a time slot that they are busy in this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore the seconds, create a string from the integer of time that only includes the Year, Month, Date, and Hour:

```
$checkdate = date('Y-m-d H', strtotime($meetingDate));
$dateconflicts = date('Y-m-d H', strtotime($_SESSION['date']));

if ( $checkdate == $dateconflicts ) {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>The dates $checkdate and $dateconflicts conflict !</div>";   
}
```

Comment: i have done your solution and now the condition is always true no matter what.

Comment: please provide example data.

Comment: @ziyad i updated the `$msg` so that you can eyeball what you are getting out of your dates.  if you are getting something unexpected, then the problem may be in the dates well before this code runs.

Comment: thank you now i have done it with ur solution with a little bit of modify in my database

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to check if 2 dates have the same hour :

```
$date1 = '2016-12-04 20:21:10';
$date2 = '2016-12-04 21:50:00';

if (date('Y-m-d H', strtotime($date1)) == date('Y-m-d H', strtotime($date2))) {
    echo 'Same hour';
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the same day, year, month as well. `they at the same time (year/month/day/hour)`

Comment: You are right @chris85, I updated my answer :)

Comment: OP is using sessions here `$_SESSION['date']` so we don't know if that array contains a value or not and as to what it is, is anyone's guess.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii-, this is true. Hopefully this will work, if `$_SESSION['date']` contains any kind of standard formatted date

Comment: I've asked for clarification in comments up there @Max and as I am typing this out, OP responded but isn't clear on that neither. All they wrote was: *"$_SESSION['date'] from previous page the user enter date"*.

Comment: thank you guys i have solved my problem. both of your solution fixed my problem.