# How to sort multi-dimesional array specifically depending on a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
Array
(
    [1150] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [start_date] => 2017-01-12 00:00:00
            [end_date] => 1485801000

        )
    [1139] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [start_date] => 2017-01-12 00:00:00
            [end_date] => 1484418600

        )
    [1131] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
            [start_date] => 2017-01-12 00:00:00
            [end_date] => 1484418600

        )
    [1123] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [start_date] => 2017-01-11 00:00:00
            [end_date] => 1484764200

        )   
)
```

Now I want to sort it on bases of descending start date.

Comment: You should maybe specify a language

Comment: By using php..!

Comment: I have to sort above mentioned array on bases of value 'start_date'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Weedoze comment but in case that it's php here are few links

http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

[How to compare two dates in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: I have to sort array using value 'start_date' value.