# need help to understand a php function

Tags: php, function, date

Need help understanding why this doesn't work. I have a text that's only visible on a given start date and time and gets removed on ended date and time.

This is the code I am using that works just fine. The text is visible for a month without problems:

```
<?php 
     if ( date('Y/m/d H:i') >= "2017/04/06 08:00" && 
          date('Y/m/d H:i') <= "2017/05/06 20:00" ) { 
         echo "$text_1"; 
     } else { 
         echo "$text_2"; 
     }
?>
```

This is how I would like to be able write the date but it doesn't work as it supposed to:

```
<?php 
     if ( date('d/m/Y H:i') >= "06/04/2017 08:00" && 
          date('d/m/Y H:i') <= "06/05/2017 20:00" ) { 
         echo "$text_1"; 
     } else { 
         echo "$text_2"; 
     }
?>
```

It doesn't take into  account the month or year. Why is that? This would only show the text for one day and not for a month.

Comment: No wonder that you don't understand it, if you don't format it properly.

Comment: feel free to elaborate what I am missing please

Comment: Is this a locale issue? `"06/04/2017 08:00"` is being interpreted as Jun-4 (American mm/dd/yy), not Apr-6 (European dd/mm/yy) as you are hoping? I'd just stick with year-month-day if it works. There are lots of date comparison examples in other answers, such as [How to compare two dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: Yeas that right it should be 6 of Aprle 2017 d = day / m = Month / Y = year or is this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change date into timestamp and then compare. Format will not matter

```
if ( strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")) >= strtotime("06/04/2017 08:00") && 
    strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")) <= strtotime("06/05/2017 20:00" )) { 
    echo "$text_1"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "$text_2"; 
}
```

Its does not matter the formate now whether `"Y-m-d H:i"` or `d/m/Y H:i`. You can do any formate.

You can also do as follows

```
if ( strtotime(date("d/m/Y H:i")) >= strtotime("06/04/2017 08:00") && 
    strtotime(date("d/m/Y H:i")) <= strtotime("06/05/2017 20:00" )) { 
    echo "aaa"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "bbb"; 
}
```

The date format really does not matter, when ever you try to compare dates, Convert that in seconds and then compare . 
Just take a lot at `strtotime()` method and do examples and see.

Comment: `strtotime(date(...))` is way too complicated. Why generate a date, formatted as string, just to parse it into a date again? See `time()`

Comment: yeah your are right @Aloso but when I was the post, this solution clicked my mind. You are right better to use time();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you compare strings using `>=` and `<=` which is not possible in most cases.

Here's what PHP does when executing the comparison `date('Y/m/d H:i') >= "2017/04/06 08:00"`:

First, the `date()` function is executed, which returns a string like `"2017/04/23 12:51"`

Since `>=` can only compare numbers, both strings are then implicitly casted into `double`. For this, PHP uses the [`strtod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html) function. This function parses a string from left to right. If the first thing it finds (except for whitespace) is a number/`infinity`/`NAN`, this number is returned. As soon as `strtod` finds a non-numeric character, the rest of the string is ignored. If `strtod` does not find a number, it returns `0`.

In this case, `strtod` returns only the year because it does not understand what a `/` means, and therefore ignores everything after the year.

---

If you want to compare dates properly, you have to use **timestamps**. To get the current timestamp, PHP offers the [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.time.php) function.

---

- [Unix `strtod()` Reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html)
- [PHP `time()` Reference](http://php.net/manual/de/function.time.php)