# Is there a way in PHP to get the amount of time lapsed?

Tags: php, datetime

I am looking to take a datetime and figure out how much time has lapsed since then...

for example, I have the following timestamp

```
2018-01-11 09:10:37
```

and I would like to output something like

```
2 days, 15 minutes
```

any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question, the mentioned question uses timestamp comparison and strtotime(). Days don't have fixed length so the best way to do this is to create two datetime objects and use the diff() method.

Comment: There is one relevant answer though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099815/1354691

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332