# How to Compare Two Date with Time in Php

Tags: php

I Need To Compare Two Date Time Variable in Php for my project what is the best way to compare

```
$date1 = "2018-02-06 15:09:44";
$date2 = "2018-02-06 16:09:44";
```

Expected Result:
I need ans as `$date2`;

Thanks in advance

Comment: What You Tried show the code

Comment: Convert them to [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and then you can use all the normal PHP comparison operators

Comment: Why would the answer to a comparison be `$date2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: Please do you research before asking new questions. Apparently this one has been asked and answered before. See my link.

Comment: i need to  delete records from mysql database . assume $date2 is current time i need to delete record < current time

Comment: sorry guys which one greater in above variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $date1 = "2018-02-06 15:09:44";
 $date2 = "2018-02-06 16:09:44";

 if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)) {
   echo "date1 less than date2";
 } else {
   echo "date1 is greater than date2;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-02-06 15:09:44");
$date2 = new DateTime("2018-02-06 16:09:44");

if($date1 > $date2 ) {
// statement
}else {
// other statement
}
```