# Comparing mysql result to current time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, strtotime

`$currentTime = date("h:i a");`

Im storing time in my db like this...
`$timeEnd = date("h:i a");` which outputs "07:15 pm".

I need to compare $expireTime to $currentTime.

`$sql2 = "UPDATE id SET expired = '1' WHERE timeEnd <= '".$currentTime."' AND date = '".$currentDate."'";`

This code works except it's not considering am/pm... what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
So it seems one answer would be to insert a 24 hour format into the db, which makes sense... is there anyway to make this work though? unix timestamp? strototime in the query?

Comment: Your time format is not doing you any favors.  I don't think I'd be passing any php variables into the query -- SQL can generate date and time values on its own.  The first step is to reformat your time format.  In other words, use military time instead using am/pm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two dates in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: The reason its formatted that way is because the user selects from a drop down menu. So i should convert it to another format before updating the db?

Comment: Definitely.  The end user's format does not need to match the db format.  The text of the `<option>` is what the user sees; the `value` of the `<option>` is what is submitted for saving.

Comment: You're right. Thats the best way, thank you

Comment: After formatting the date and time, this query should solve your need, since time is stored on the DB using 24H format as default. `UPDATE id SET expired = '1'
WHERE time(timeEnd) <= '".$currentTime."' AND date(date) = '".$currentDate."'";`